# Codeigniter TWIG: How to access global variable in template

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig, codeigniter-3

How can I access model functions in .twig templates?

```
{% if($this->my_model->my_function("123")) %}
    Hello World
{% endif %}
```

This returns `Unexpected character "$"`

EDIT:

I realised I can do something like this

`$this->twig->addGlobal("my_function", $this->my_model->my_function("123") ? true : false)`

But considering `123` can be anything, I don't know how I'd allow input of a parameter.

Comment: You can't use $ or php syntax in twig. How do you give your variables to your view?

Comment: I use `$this->twig->addGlobal`

Comment: It could be accessible like `my_model.my_function("123")`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything, no errors but no results either

Comment: Updated my question with info I discovered

Comment: Try `$this->twig->addGlobal("my_model", $this->my_model);` and then in Twig: `{% if my_model.my_function("123") %}` where `"123"` can be anything.

Comment: @martias Yes, that worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the model as a global variable instead of the function:

```
$this->twig->addGlobal("my_model", $this->my_model);
```

Then in Twig you can do (`"123"` can be anything):

```
{% if my_model.my_function("123") %}
    Hello World
{% endif %}
```